# Filter data is not getting copied to the new worksheet. Only blank file is getting saved

Tags: excel, vba

Goal of this code:

Apply filter at Range A2 in Final Salary Sheet based upon value of Menu Sheet Range "E6"
Copy A1:M1 data as header
and then Copy filter data to A2 range in new sheet, rename the new sheet and save the new sheet to specific folder with specified name.

Error I am facing:

A1:m1 range is perfectly getting copy pasted. but filter data is not getting copy pasted. Also please note A1 range in Final Salary Sheet is a Logo/Image.

```
Sub selfcopy()

Dim exclfile As String
Dim fdObj As Object
    Dim year As String
    Dim month As String
    
    year = Sheets("Menu").Range("e4").Text
    month = Sheets("Menu").Range("e6").Text
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set fdObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If fdObj.FolderExists("\\Account\e\SATYA\BANK\1-SALARY SHEET\1-TRANSFER\" & year & "\" & month) Then
        On Error Resume Next
            Else
        fdObj.CreateFolder ("\\Account\e\SATYA\BANK\1-SALARY SHEET\1-TRANSFER\" & year & "\" & month)
          End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

exclfile = "Salary File" & "-" & Sheets("Menu").Range("E6").Text
   
               
  Set Newbook = Workbooks.Add
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Final Salary").Select
Range("A1:M1").copy
Newbook.Worksheets("UBI Bank").Range("A1").Activate
Activesheet.paste
Newbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Name = "Salaryoutput"
  Newbook.Worksheets("Salaryoutput").Select
  
  
  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Final Salary").Select
        Range("A2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$W$99999").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array(1, Sheets("Menu").Range("E6").Text)
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
  Selection.Copy
    Newbook.Worksheets("salaryoutput").Range("A2").Activate
  ActiveSheet.Paste

  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  
   Newbook.SaveAs Filename:="\\Account\e\SATYA\BANK\1-SALARY SHEET\1-TRANSFER\" & year & "\" & month & "\" & exclfile
   
   ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Menu").Select
   MsgBox ("Excel has been saved to Bank Folder")
End Sub
```

I am quite new with Excel VBA.

Comment: Remove the `On Error Resume Next` line and try it again. That should help you narrow down the issues.

Comment: issue still persistent

Comment: Are you getting an error now? I'd be very surprised if not.

Answer (score 0):

This line `Newbook.Worksheets("UBI Bank").Range("A1").Activate` fails because a new book will not have a sheet with that name.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub selfcopy()

    Const FOLDER = "\\Account\e\SATYA\BANK\1-SALARY SHEET\1-TRANSFER\"
    
    Dim wbNew As Workbook
    Dim fdObj As Object, exclfile As String, exclfolder As String
    Dim year As Long, month As Long, lastrow As Long
    
    With Sheets("Menu")
        year = .Range("E4").Value2
        month = .Range("E6").Value2
        exclfile = "Salary File" & "-" & Format(month, "00")
        exclfolder = FOLDER & year & "\" & month
    End With
    
    Set fdObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If Not fdObj.FolderExists(exclfolder) Then
        fdObj.CreateFolder exclfolder
        MsgBox exclfolder & " created"
    End If
    
    Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With wbNew
        .Sheets(1).Name = "Salaryoutput"
    End With
               
    With Sheets("Final Salary")
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("A1:M1").Copy wbNew.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
        With .Range("A2:W" & lastrow)
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=month
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy wbNew.Sheets(1).Range("A2")
        End With
    End With
    
    wbNew.SaveAs Filename:=exclfolder & "\" & exclfile
    wbNew.Close savechanges:=False
    
    Sheets("Menu").Activate
    MsgBox "Excel has been saved to " & exclfile, vbInformation, exclfolder
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but i am getting the following error on running the above code:  "Run-Time error "13", type mismatch.

Comment: @jagdish which line has the error ?